# What is the value of integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $y(t)$ be a continuous function on $[0,\infty)$. If $$ y(t)= t\left(1-4 \int^t_0 y(x) dx\right) +4 \int^t_0 xy(x) dx$$ then  what is the value of $\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_0 y(t) dt\,$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiating we get
$$
y'=1-4\int_0^ty(x)dx-4ty+4ty=1-4\int_0^ty(x)dx.
$$
Differentiating again, we obtain
$$
y''=-4y,
$$
which has the solutions $y(t)=a\cos(2t)+b\sin(2t)$. Substituting in the original equation gives
$$
a\cos(2t)+b\sin(2t)=t[1-2a\sin(2t)+2\cos(2t)-2]+4\int_0^t s(a\cos(2s)+b\sin(2s))ds.
$$
Solving for $a$ and $b$, you finally compute (using the identity in the first differentiation)
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}y(x)dx=\frac{1-y'(\pi/2)}4=\frac{1+2b}4.
$$

Comment: Your calculation of $y'$ is wrong and hence the equation $y''=-4y$ is wrong too. Thus your answer is totally wrong.

Comment: @xpaul Care to say why?

Answer (score 1):

Jonas's reasoning also shows that $y'(0) = 1$ and since $y(0) = 0$ from the defining equation there is enough information to determine that $a=0$ and $2b=1$.