# If $y(t) = t\left(1-\int_0^ty(x)\,dx\right)+4\int_0^tx\,y(x)\,dx,$ then $\int_0^{\pi/2} y(t)\,dt$ is equal to?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Leibniz rule or Laplace transform?

> Let $y(t)$ be a continuous function on $[0,\infty)$. If 
>   $$y(t) = t\left(1-4\int_0^ty(x)\,dx\right)+4\int_0^tx\,y(x)\,dx,$$
>   then $\int_0^{\pi/2} y(t)\,dt$ is equal to __________.

[Source.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CebSR.png)

I solved this question using Leibniz rule and converting this Fredholm integral equation into ordinary differential equation and got my answer to be $0.5$.

First of all is it correct?
Secondly somebody said you could solve this using Laplace transformation also assuming it exists for $y$? Can be somebody show me how to do this?

Comment: Are you sure this is Fredholm I. E.?

Comment: I am sorry this volterra

Comment: Do you have a background  about Laplace transform?

Comment: Not much but i know how to find laplace transforms

Comment: Then take the Laplace transform of the equation you w. r.  to t and see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/140106/volterra-integral-equation-of-second-type-solve-using-resolvent-kernel/425186#425186).

Comment: I don't understand how to take the laplace transform and convlution ?please solve my question for me the way you are saying it would be of great help

Comment: That's why I asked you about your background!  You need to more about Laplace transform to solve such eq. By the way your eq.  is not convolution type.

Comment: Ohk.then what do i do

Comment: As I said take some time to learn more about Laplace transform!  Even if people solved it for you you would not be able to understand their solution!

Comment: Oh then plz solve it using lebnitz rule as i am not sure of my answer

Comment: See the second approach in my [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/408777/volterra-integral-equation-with-variable-boundaries).

Comment: Identical to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1643665/what-is-the-value-of-integral/1643695#1643695 which received an elementary solution